# Cloud CDN with Cloud Storage as Backend

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

Cloud Storage backend for Google Cloud CDN is currently in alpha. When I trie to use/enable it I get following error:

```
$ gcloud alpha compute backend-buckets update static-bucket --gcs-bucket-name my-bucket --enable-cdn
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.compute.backend-buckets.update) There was a problem fetching the resource:
 - Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API'
```

How to get Alpha Access? I also don't see any apply form for Alpha Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation page "[HTTP(S) Load Balancing with Google Cloud Storage Contents](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/using-http-lb-with-cloud-storage)", there's a box with a [link to a page to request access](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1TaRyYUgRgUsMEm774J_b42utzEiUzfqcakmY9bnrQ5I/viewform).